# How to send String Array as param to srver and Getting error while uploading data on server --onErrorResponse (VolleyError error)

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-volley

i am sending some data to server in order to save it in server database. But i keep on getting error. I used the same method in some other cases also and its working fine. But i don't know why in this case its not working.please tell me the correct way to upload data and also how to send data as String Array to server. Because as u can see i keep 'category' and 'subcategory' as null because the data of these two are in array(multiple choices selected by the user)... Please Help :) 
Here is My uploadData method:

```
        private void uploadData(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,UPLOAD_URL,new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("sub response", response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String er=error.getMessage();
                    Log.d("error is",er);
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateUserProfile.this,er,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Log.d("","error message"+er);
                }
            }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id",user_id);
            params.put("first_name",f_name.getText().toString());
            params.put("last_name",l_name.getText().toString());
            params.put("mobile_number",contact.getText().toString());
            params.put("zip_code",z_code.getText().toString());
            params.put("state",state_id_only);
            params.put("region",region_id_only);
            params.put("address",user_address.getText().toString());
            params.put("category",null);
            params.put("sub_category",null);
            params.put("advertise_image",image);

            return params;
        }

    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}  //end =================purpose==========================
```

and each time i click on the button to upload the data i get this exception:

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
        at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
        at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
        at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getParams()`

```
params.put("category",null);
params.put("sub_category",null);
```

Don't pass `null` for values, instead of that pass `""`

```
params.put("category","");
params.put("sub_category","");
```

may be thats why its getting error.

About sending an array of data:
 You can try with `JSONArray` to send array of data.

Answer (score 0):

i Have got second problem's solution also.. here it is:

```
     int i=0;
            for(String object: selectedcate){
             params.put("category["+(i++)+"]", object);
            }
           // params.put("category","");
            int s=0;
            for(String object: selected_sub_cate){
                params.put("sub_category["+(s++)+"]", object);
            }
```

In this way we can send both String and String array as params...